# in menu driven program printing the highest priority Using Priority Queue and Heap

Tags: c++

So basically i am trying to implement a menu driven program using Priority Queue and Heap to accept incoming patient’s name and an integer that indicates the seriousness of their condition.  This integer is a value between 1 and 5 – 1 being a minor illness and 5 being a critical condition

The code i have got for Heap

```
#include <iostream>

template<class ItemType>
// Assumes ItemType is either a built-in simple  // type or a class with overloaded relational    // operators.
struct HeapType
{
    void ReheapDown(int root, int bottom);
    void ReheapUp(int root, int bottom);
    ItemType* elements;                                       // Array to be allocated dynamically
    int numElements;

    //new
    void Swap(ItemType& x, ItemType& y);
};

template<class ItemType>
void HeapType<ItemType>::ReheapDown(int root, int bottom)
// Post: Heap property is restored.
{
    int maxChild;
    int rightChild;
    int leftChild;
    leftChild = root * 2 + 1;
    rightChild = root * 2 + 2;
    if (leftChild <= bottom)
    {
        if (leftChild == bottom)
            maxChild = leftChild;
        else
        {
            if (elements[leftChild] <= elements[rightChild])
                maxChild = rightChild;
            else
                maxChild = leftChild;
        }
        if (elements[root] < elements[maxChild])
        {
            Swap(elements[root], elements[maxChild]);
            ReheapDown(maxChild, bottom);
        }
    }
}


template<class ItemType>
void HeapType<ItemType>::ReheapUp(int root, int bottom)
// Post: Heap property is restored.
{
    int parent;
    if (bottom > root)
    {
        parent = (bottom - 1) / 2;
        if (elements[parent] < elements[bottom])
        {
            Swap(elements[parent], elements[bottom]);
            ReheapUp(root, parent);
        }
    }
}

// New
// Swapp items
template<class ItemType>
void HeapType<ItemType>::Swap(ItemType& x, ItemType& y) {

    ItemType t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
}
```

The code i have got for Priority Queue

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Heap.h"

using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>

class PQType
{
public:
    PQType(int);                                // parameterized class constructor
    ~PQType();                                // class destructor
    void MakeEmpty();
    // Function: Initializes the queue to an empty
    // state.
    // Post: Queue is empty.
    bool IsEmpty() const;
    // Function: Determines whether the queue is
    // empty.
    // Post: Function value = (queue is empty)
    bool IsFull() const;
    // Function: Determines whether the queue is
    // full.
    // Post: Function value = (queue is full)
    void Enqueue(ItemType newItem);
    // Function: Adds newItem to the rear of the
    // queue.
    // Pre:  Queue is not full.
    // Post: newItem is in the queue.
    void Dequeue(ItemType& item);
    // Function: Removes element with highest
    // priority from the queue
    // and returns it in item.
    // Pre:  Queue is not empty.
    // Post: Highest priority element has been 
    //       removed from the queue.
    //       item is a copy of the removed element
    void Print();

  private:
    int numItems;
    HeapType<ItemType> items;
    int maxItems;
};

template<class ItemType>
PQType<ItemType>::PQType(int max)
{
    maxItems = max;
    items.elements = new ItemType[max];
    numItems = 0;
}

template<class ItemType>
PQType<ItemType>::~PQType()
{
    delete[] items.elements;
}

template<class ItemType>
void PQType<ItemType>::MakeEmpty()
{
    numItems = NULL;
}

template<class ItemType>
bool PQType<ItemType>::IsEmpty() const
// Post: Function value = true if the queue is   //         empty; false, otherwise
{
    return numItems == 0;
}
template<class ItemType>
bool PQType<ItemType>::IsFull() const
// Post: Function value = true if the queue is   //         full; false, otherwise
{
    return numItems == maxItems;
}

template<class ItemType>
void PQType<ItemType>::Enqueue(ItemType newItem)
// Post: newItem is in the queue.
{
    numItems++;
    items.elements[numItems - 1] = newItem;
    items.ReheapUp(0, numItems - 1);
}

template<class ItemType>
void PQType<ItemType>::Dequeue(ItemType& item)
// Post: element with highest priority has been  
// removed from the queue; a copy is returned in item.
{
    item = items.elements[0];
    items.elements[0] = items.elements[numItems - 1];
    numItems--;
    items.ReheapDown(0, numItems - 1);
}

template <class ItemType>
void PQType<ItemType>::Print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= numItems - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "\t " << items.elements[i].name << " \t " << items.elements[i].priority << endl;
    }
}
```

The code for main page i have got

```
#include "Priority_Queue.h"
#include "Heap.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


struct Patient
{
    string name;
    int priority;

    bool operator < (Patient P1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool operator <= (Patient P1) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    bool operator > (Patient P1) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool operator >= (Patient P1) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool operator == (Patient P1) 
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string x = "2";
    int y = 0;

    Patient P1 = { "Tom", 3 };
    Patient P2 = { "Mary", 4 };
    Patient P3 = { "Fred", 3 };
    Patient P4 = { "Sarah", 1 };
    Patient P5 = { "Ann", 5 };
    Patient P6 = { "Mike", 4 };
    Patient PUser = { x , y };

    PQType<Patient> pQueue(100);

   /* pQueue.Enqueue(P1);
    pQueue.Enqueue(P2);
    pQueue.Enqueue(P3);
    pQueue.Enqueue(P4);
    pQueue.Enqueue(P5);*/

    int choice, priority;
    string name = "";

    do
    {
        cout << "1.Insert\n";
        cout << "2.Delete\n";
        cout << "3.Display\n";
        cout << "4.Quit\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice : ";

        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter Patient`s name: ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Enter the priority: ";
            cin >> priority;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Enter Patient`s name: ";
            cin >> name;
            break;

        case 3:
            pQueue.Print();
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

         default:

            cout << endl;
            cout << "Wrong choice\n";
            cout << endl;
        }

    } while (choice != 4);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask a question.

Comment: Sorry about that. What i am trying to do is to print the patient with the highest number first. like "Ann", 5 should be printed first or whoever has the highest number then lesser numbered patients

Comment: You need to update your question so that it actually asks whatever question you want people to answer, otherwise it will get closed as "needs more focus" (or similar).  If you just want general help debugging, then I suggest this article:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You can't enumerate a heap-based priority queue as if it were already a sorted sequence. You can only *process* it. Each time you pull from the head the queue is re-heaped (how that happens varies on your algorithm). Therefore, you can pop+print everything off the queue, shoving it all on to a new queue as you go, then swap queues when you're done. Note that this can (and nearly always does) expose inconsistency in how same-priority items are ordered on re-queuing as you'll often find them seem to 'swap' places.